# Issue with inserting list items with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, append

Pretty new to jQuery here, but I'm trying to insert an unordered list into the DOM, and then subsequently insert list items. The `<ul>` is being inserted correctly and is being given the class `.newList`, but `<li>` elements aren't being appended. Shouldn't `.append` insert them into the `ul`?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!--List inserted with jQuery-->
<button id="modifyExample2">Click me to insert a list!</button>
```

And here is my script:

```
    $("#modifyExample2").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).prev("ul").hasClass("newList")) {
            $(".newList").append("<li>New list item!</li>");
        } else {
            $("<ul>My new list!</ul>").insertBefore(this);
            $(this).prev("ul").addClass("newList");
            $("#modifyExample2").text("Click me again to insert list items!");
        }
    });
```

Here it is in JSFiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzj6kp7g/21/)

Is there something I'm misunderstanding / missing?

Comment: `addClass/hasClass('className')` should not have a `.`-dot

Comment: Also your fiddle is using onload and document.ready - use either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo; when using `addClass` and `hasClass` you don't need to use the `.` prefix:

```
if ($(this).prev("ul").hasClass("newList")) {
    $(".newList").append("<li>New list item!</li>");
} else {
    $("<ul>My new list!</ul>").insertBefore(this);
    $(this).prev("ul").addClass("newList");
    $("#modifyExample2").text("Click me again to insert list items!");
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pzj6kp7g/7/)

Note that you can also tidy the logic a little:

```
$("#modifyExample2").on("click", function () {
    var $ul = $(this).prev('ul');        
    if ($ul.hasClass("newList")) {
        $ul.append("<li>New list item!</li>");
    } else {
        $("<ul>My new list!</ul>").addClass("newList").insertBefore(this);
        $(this).text("Click me again to insert list items!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, missed that one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan got there first. This is the correct answer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks muchly for spotting that and for the tidying pointers! Syntax errors really are the kryptonite of beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click","#modifyExample2", function () {
        if ($(this).prev().hasClass("newList")) {
            $(this).prev().append("<li>New list item!</li>");
        } else {
            $("<ul>My new list!</ul>").insertBefore(this);
            $(this).prev("ul").addClass("newList");
            $(this).text("Click me again to insert list items!");
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pzj6kp7g/12/)

Comment: Nope. No dots in the hasClass and addClass. Also no need to delegate unless the button is dynamically inserted

Comment: This is fine, as long as you're not using `'.newList'` as a selector. No need to downvote here

Comment: NOW it is fine. It was not fine originally and I have removed the down vote. Chrome does not work with the dots in the hasClass and addClass. Now it is just identical to [the first correct post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29649410/295783) except for the unnecessary delegation

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pzj6kp7g/9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#modifyExample2").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).prev("ul").hasClass("newList")) {
            $(".newList").append("<li>New list item!</li>");
        } else {
            $("<ul>My new list!</ul>").insertBefore(this);
            $(this).prev("ul").addClass("newList");
            $("#modifyExample2").text("Click me again to insert list items!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The class name for the `ul` has to be `newList` rather than `.newList`

```
$("#modifyExample2").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).prev("ul").hasClass("newList")) {
        $(".newList").append("<li>New list item!</li>");
    } else {
        $("<ul>My new list!</ul>").insertBefore(this);
        $(this).prev("ul").addClass("newList");
        $("#modifyExample2").text("Click me again to insert list items!");
    }
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzj6kp7g/8/)